# filebeat configuration: override default for close_inactive for all inputs

Tags: filebeat

i know i could use the cmdline parameter `-M "*.*.input.close_inactive=1h"`, but i am looking for a way to do exactly that but in the configuration file which is generated by graylog, since graylog does not allow to configure the parameter `close_inactive` for the inputs, but it allows to add a global raw configuration snippet to the generated configuration.

is this possible? and if so, as of which version?

many thanks

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
filebeat.prospector.close_inactive: 1h
```

in version 6 `propector` was renamed to `input`